# How to invoke javascript function every time after another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have two tables and I move particular rows among them when clicking corresponding checkboxes.
Besides checkboxes each row contains in-line editing fields thanks to x-editable library.

The problem is when I move some row into another table I can't edit its fields anymore. It seems like setXeditable() runs only one time and then after invoking another java script it doesn't get executed. I have to reload the page to be able to edit these fields again. How can I solve it?

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap3-editable/bootstrap-editable
//= require bootstrap-datepicker/core
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require_tree .

#x-editable

var setXeditable;

$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

setXeditable = function() {
  return $("[data-xeditable=true]").each(function() {
    return $(this).editable({
      ajaxOptions: {
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json"
      },
      params: function(params) {
        var railsParams;
        railsParams = {};
        railsParams[$(this).data("model")] = {};
        railsParams[$(this).data("model")][params.name] = params.value;
        return railsParams;
      }
    });
  });
};

#function that moves rows

function pressing(arg){
      user_id = $(arg).attr('data-user-id')
      id = $(arg).attr('data-id')
      value = $(arg).is(":checked")
      $(arg).attr('data-id')
      html=$(arg).closest("tr")
      $(arg).closest("tr").remove()
      path = '/users/' + user_id + '/tasks/' + id

       if(value){
         complete = true;
         $('.completed-tasks').append(html)
       }
       else{
         complete = false;
          $('.incompleted-tasks').append(html)
        }

      $.ajax({
        url : path,
        type : 'PUT',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { task: {id: id, complete: value}}
      })
    }
```

I'm calling setXeditable() in my **index.js**

```
$("#all-tasks").html("<%= j render 'index' %>")

setXeditable()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just add a call to `setXeditable()` from the move row function?

```
function pressing(arg){
      user_id = $(arg).attr('data-user-id')
      id = $(arg).attr('data-id')
      value = $(arg).is(":checked")
      $(arg).attr('data-id')
      html=$(arg).closest("tr")
      $(arg).closest("tr").remove()
      path = '/users/' + user_id + '/tasks/' + id

       if(value){
         complete = true;
         $('.completed-tasks').append(html)
       }
       else{
         complete = false;
          $('.incompleted-tasks').append(html)
        }

        setXeditable();

      $.ajax({
        url : path,
        type : 'PUT',
        dataType: "json",
        data: { task: {id: id, complete: value}}
      })
    }
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problems with this. Otherwise, could you please accept my answer?